# Error while Running Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I got this error some minutes after I started it. THe error says "Error Load Library 87 - Incorrect Parameter".

When I click OK Netbeans crash.

Image here:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/QguN7.png

Comment: I tried this: https://servicecore.info/2012/09/how-to-fix-loadlibrary-failed-with-error-126-problem-on-windows-systems/   Im still testing it.

Comment: The method used in the comment below solved the problem.